# Why might navigator.bluetooth be undefined?

Tags: android, bluetooth, web-bluetooth, android-chrome

Tablet: Lenovo tab4 8

Android version: `8.1`

Android Chrome version: `76.0.3809.111`

Bluetooth 'switch' in Settings is turned on.

Site is being served over `https://`

And yet: `navigator.bluetooth` is `undefined`

- This means that this page, which does useful bluetooth things, does not work on this tablet.

---

Is there any other setting or something that I may be missing?

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that `navigator.bluetooth` in fact was not `undefined` - instead the Google Closure JS compiler (which we use for optimization/minimization) was minify-ing `navigator.bluetooth` to `navigator.uG`, and `navigator.uG` was `undefined`.

This was easily corrected by specifying externs.

Not a web-bluetooth problem after all, but perhaps this will be helpful to some future searcher.

Take care.